# Is there a way to have Laravel not convert symbols to html codes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am working on a template for my home page, pulling html for certain sections from the database.  For example, I have a slider with editable text.  The text stored in the DB for slide two is

```
"Name is a multipurpose venue <br /> Empowering people and their passions"
```

But when I return this in my template, it converts the < to `&lt;` and > to `&gt;` which just causes "`<br />`" to display on the page.

Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: Per the docs, "By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically send through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax: `Hello, {!! $name !!}.`"

Answer (score 9):

To echo out a string without any alterations, use `{!! !!}` syntax instead of `{{ }}`.

Comment: Note this doesn't protect him from xss since he is getting the data from the database. Is this data user input?